# Receiving an array of Object from a web form using Spring framework

Tags: java, spring

I have a form JSP web page, this form contains multiple instances of the same Java object,
I am using Java Spring Framework to control the "communication" with the controller and the view.

My problem is that I would like to be able to receive from the view a simple array containing the instances of my objects which are currently on the page (on which were probably modified).

When I want a specific kind of item, I usually just name it in my controller's method declaration, however for an array (or any Collection), this won't work.

so something like:

```
@RequestMapping
public String edit(...SomeObject[] objectName, ...){
}
```

would just return me an error, I can however receive an array of String, so this works:

```
@RequestMapping
public String edit(...String[] objectString, ...){
}
```

the goal would be to be able to make Spring automatically map the object.
thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring does not know how to create your custom object from a String so you will need to create your own PropertyEditor for your custom object.

[Chapter 5](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/validation.html) of the Spring Reference explains data binding and there is an [example](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/mvc.html#mvc-ann-initbinder) in Chapter 13 of how to register custom property editors in your controller.

Comment: If you're converting something like a string to a date, yes, property editors are certainly needed.

However, if you're submitting a form with foo=a, foo=b and foo=c, Spring MVC is smart enough to turn that into a List<String> named "foo"...

Comment: i was confused about initBinder and what was a property editor but i found an exemple there 
http://robobruin.blogspot.com/2007/09/spring-initbinder-example-that.html

Comment: the thing i need to receive is rather something like 
foo.atr1 = a
foo.atr2 = b

List<Object> foo

Comment: ah, i can see why spring would have a hard time; from spring's perspective, foo.atr1 and foo.atr2 are two different parameters. if you need something like that though, you can probably dump them in a map by naming them foo['atr1'] = a

Answer (score 2):

This is certainly possible; while I've not done it using @RequestMapping, I know that you can retrieve a collection it can be done with a "command" object (or @ModelAttribute)

Define a POJO with a collection attribute as your command

```
public class FooCommand {
    private List<String> myCollection;
    // Getter & Setter
}
```

Then access it in your controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/foo", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String processSubmit(@ModelAttribute("fooCommand") FooCommand fooCmd) {
    // do stuff with fooCmd.getMyCollection() 
}
```

That make any sense?

Comment: that works, however, what i need is to be able to receiving something other than a String, i would like Spring to automatically map the received String to a POJO

Comment: What kind of object? If can handle stuff like string, long, int, char (i think) but if it's a more complex object, you'll need to work with the property editor mentioned by Mark.

Comment: my object contains strings and integers, it can map 1 item, the problem arises when i try to map an array or a list of item

Comment: if i try to ask for a list, i receive a GenericSignatureFormatError
Exception, if i try to ask for an array, i get:

Could not instantiate bean class [SrbAdminInvMask;]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: [SrbAdminInvMask;.<init>()

Comment: Can you post a more code? GenericSignatureFormatError is a really odd error to get, as is the default contructor problem...

Comment: i'm sorry i cannot really post more code, but i finally used a different approach, i do the conversion from a String to the object myself. I think i was getting the GenericSignatureFormatError since i was trying to get a "List" wich if i remember correctly cannot be instanciated by itself